# How to subtract two sets of values in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sets of values in `A:A` and `B:B`. How to make a set difference between them (preferably using a formula), i.e. get those values from `A:A` that do not exist in `B:B`?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Such a formula does this, and is quite fast:

```
=filter(A:A,countif(B:B,A:A)=0)
```

The way this works is the `arrayformula` behavior in `filter`'s second argument. `countif` accepts a range and a single criteria or value. So each element of `A:A` is passed to `countif` one at a time, counting the occurrence of said element within `B:B`.

Comment: Works ! but is case insensitive. How would be a case sensitive version ?

Comment: case sensitive version: `=query(A:A, "select A where A != '"&join("' and A != '",B:B)&"'")`

Comment: While this works, it uses undocumented functionality where `COUNTIF(range, x)` has an argument of type range in the second argument slot x. Also see the note I put in marc meyer's answer where this might 'ignore' or 'hide' some results.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing as @ninjagecko...namely what is happening with the `COUNTIF(range, range)`. How does that work exactly??? Does that run for each cell of `A:A`? When I put that into a separate cell it just returns a `TRUE`, so I'm not sure how it is running for each part of the `A:A` we are filtering. Can someone help explain how this actually works?

Answer (score 13):

Here’s a spreadsheet showing how set operations can be done easily:

[Set Operations in Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-beBOT1CjVyny7QwLz-RQCeN6fDTcIpLI1iZIjdTSgI/edit?usp=sharing)

- **Union** is `={setA; setB}`
- **Difference** (setA-setB) is `=filter(setA, iserror(MATCH(setA, setB, false)))`
- **Intersection** is `=filter(setA; MATCH(setA, setB, false))`

**Explanation:**

`setA` and `setB` can be named ranges or you can use normal range notation. Named ranges just make this clearer.

**Union** is just a new range made by juxtaposing both ranges.

**Intersection** (next easiest) depends on looking for indices of `setA` in `setB` where they exits, and filtering `setA` by that.

**Difference** is similar, but filters `setA` to pick out only members where finding the index in `setB` is not found.

**Extra Credit:**

Union with duplicate elimination is just `setA + (setB-setA)`, so by the above:

```
={setA;filter(setB, iserror(MATCH(setB,setA,false)))}
```

Comment: This may seem to 'ignore' or 'hide' some results, because blanks are kept (maybe they're considered as values or somesuch), but in reality if you are expecting values and aren't seeing them, scroll very far down. The way I dealt with this is to replace all instances of `setA` with `FILTER(setA, LEN(setA))`, which basically pre-prunes all `isblank`/empty rows away before doing the set operation.

Comment: That google sheets link is gold. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this formula:

```
=FILTER(A:A,REGEXMATCH(A:A&" ",JOIN("|",FILTER(B:B,B:B<>"")))=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Works, but is a bit slow for larger sets.

Comment: I have about 300 rows in both sets.