# How to calculate difference of two ranges in google spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to calculate the difference of two sets in a google spreadsheet:

[image: ResulSet = Set1-Set2]

What is the best way to do so? As far as I have seen there is no native function for this.

Comment: See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37653297/how-to-subtract-two-sets-of-values-in-google-spreadsheets

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you wish to determine values that are in `Set 1`, but are omitted in `Set 2` then the following formula will achieve this:

```
=FILTER( A1:A , ISERROR( MATCH( A1:A , B1:B , 0 ) ) )
```

If you wish to determine values in `Set 2` that are not part of `Set 1`, you can use the following:

```
= FILTER( B1:B , ISERROR( MATCH( B1:B , A1:A , 0 ) ) )
```

Comment: Wow, that was a quick answer. And it solved my problem as well. Thank you very much!

Comment: This worked well. Scott, can you explain how this works? I don't understand how it's possible to pass the full range that we're filtering over as the first parameter to `MATCH`. I thought `MATCH` would only accept a single cell as its first parameter, and not a range. I see that this style is common from the documentation for `FILTER`. I am seeking to understand the mechanics.

Comment: @mon4goos Sorry for the late reply. It has been some time since I answered this question, but `MATCH` accepts a range of values and not just a single cell.